# Download_file from s3 Bucket to as EC2 root path

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am having some trouble trying to download an xml file from `my_bucket`.

Example:

```
s3:Path: my_bucket>>First_archives_file>>Second_archives_file>>xmlFile.xml
```

I was trying with these methods:

```
for row2 in self.cursor.fetchall():
        print(row2[0].strip())#PATH : prueba-cgirano/LoadXml/AME880912I89/2018/01/0628757E-7FEC-4A9B-961F-69F1A62875C0.xml
        print(row2[1].strip())#FILE_NAME : 0628757E-7FEC-4A9B-961F-69F1A62875C0

        path = python_path(str(row2[1].strip()+'.xml')).replace('\\','/')
        print(path) #/root/0628757E-7FEC-4A9B-961F-69F1A62875C0.xml

        print('path')
        try:
            #self.s3.Bucket('my_bucket').download_file(str(row2[1].strip()+'.xml'),str(row2[1].strip()+'.xml'))
            self.s33 = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id='MY_KEY',aws_secret_access_key='MY_ACCESS_KEY')
            #self.s33.download_file('my_bucket',str(row2[1].strip()+'.xml'),path+str(row2[1].strip()+'.xml'))
            self.s33.download_file('pruebas-cgirano',str(row2[0].strip().replace('pruebas-cgirano/','')),path)

            result = self.print_info(path)
            print(result)
            if e.response['Error']['Code']=="404":
                print('The object does not exist.')
            else:
                raise
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
```

But it gives me this Error:

**An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found**

I need to surf on many archive_file to get the xmlFile then download to my EC2 instance to manage the content. I already have the logic to manage the content, the problem is that I can not download the xml File to my EC2 instance.

Comment: It is indicating that the object was not found in the S3 bucket. The easiest way to debug is to `print (str(row2[1].strip()+'.xml'))` immediately before the `download_file()` command to verify what Key it is trying to access.  Then, confirm that the object exists with that Key. By the look of your code, the object would need to be in the root of the bucket, with no path prefix. If you really think that the object exists, use the AWS CLI to try to download the object to confirm whether it exists with the expected name.

Comment: In reading your question again, it seems that you are saying the object is in sub-folders in S3. However, your `download_file()` command is referencing only the name of the object, without the full path. Therefore, S3 cannot find the object.

Comment: HeadObject operation: Not Found ---> indicating the wrong path is being passed.
Try printing the all the paths or just use this method for first level object in your bucket.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein is correct. the object is in sub_folders from an s3 Bucket. so should i do this: self.s3.Bucket('my_bucket').download_file(FULL_PATH+str(row2[1].strip()+'.xml'),str(row2[1].strip()+'.xml'))?

Comment: You should do whatever generates the correct full path to the object. It is not possible for us to confirm if your code is correct because we cannot see the values being passed into `self.cursor.fetchall()`, so you will need to debug it yourself. I suggest you start by hard-coding the values in the `download_file()` line to verify that it works, then work backwards to generate the correct values based on `row2`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i edited the  rows information---- pruebas-cgirano is the bucket name the rest of the path are the sub_files till get to tha xmlFile

Comment: Your code shows a PATH in `row2[0]`, yet your code never uses it. Therefore, S3 cannot find the object. The `download_file()` command takes the object `Key` as the 2nd parameter. The Key should be the full name of the object, which includes the path. So, it should be something like: `LoadXml/AME880912I89/2018/01/0628757E-7FEC-4A9B-961F-69F1A62875C0.xml`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i did the some test editing it like self.s33.download_file('pruebas-cgirano',str(row2[0].strip().replace('pruebas-cgirano/','')),path), same error

Comment: The problem is totally related to the information being passed into the parameters. The code is referring to an object that does not exist. You should `print()` each of the parameters being passed to `download_object()`, then confirm whether they are correct. You can use `aws s3 cp` to try to copy the object to help with debugging.

Comment: Hi, guys i fixed it, wrong bucket name, full path was correct!. Thanks for your help.